# Table Navigation and row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-plugins

I have an HTML table which contains about 1000 rows and 26 columns. I am using [this jQuery plugin](http://projects.arkanis-development.de/table_navigation/) to navigate between rows and make a selection.

My first problem is that the plugin is working fine, but—even using the latest version (0.6.1)—it's very slow when working with 1000 rows.

My second problem is that I want to create a JSON object representing the selected row from the table. I wrote a function that does this, but again it's too slow on such a big table. The following code works, but I want to optimise it:

```
$(document).bind("keyup", function(event) {
    var jsonText = "";
    var i = 0;
    var td_size = $("tr.selected td").size();
    jsonText += "{";
    for (i = 0; i < td_size; i++) {
        if (i < td_size - 1) {
            if (i == 0) {
                // Get link URL.
                jsonText += "\"" + $("thead tr th").eq(i).text() + "\":\"" + $("tr.selected td").eq(i).find("a").attr("href") + "\",";
            } else {
                jsonText += "\"" + $("thead tr th").eq(i).text() + "\":\"" + $("tr.selected td").eq(i).text() + "\",";
            }
        }
        else {
            jsonText += "\"" + $("thead tr th").eq(i).text() + "\":\"" + $("tr.selected td").eq(i).text() + "\"";
        }
    }
    jsonText += "}";
    $('#content').html('').append(jsonText);
});
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I think any script will be slow with 1000 rows. Have you thought about breaking the table up a bit more? Or presenting blocks of the table at a time?

Comment: The data has been retrieved from the view instead of table. The problem is not with fetching of data because i Analise that retrieving records and creating HTML table through looping in dataset took only two minutes but most of the time (approximately 12-15 seconds) has been taken by the plugin and the code which i have created to generate JSON object of selected row.

Comment: Assuming I haven't missed anything in the source, there seem to be a couple of performance issues with this plugin: first, it binds key events on *each row* instead of on e.g. the whole table; and second, instead of caching the next row in the table, it does a selector query. The former especially will be driving up initialisation time and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is optimize your jQuery selectors to help the Sizzler work faster...
instead of biding on keyup of all document, how about keyup of a specific tr?

```
$("tr.selected td").size(); // slow

$("table").find(".selected").find("td"); // probably faster
```

Save the selected tr outside the loop, you're asking the sizzler to find your object 26 times by looping 1000 rows!

```
$("thead tr th").eq(i) // on every loop element? slow, try saving the information before the keyup event, they are not going anywhere are they?
```

So probably something like this would be faster:

```
var $allTrs = $("tr");
var $allHeads = $("thead tr th");

$allTrs.bind("keyup", function(event) {
    var jsonText = "";
    var i = 0;
    var $t = $(this),
        $alltds = $t.find("td"),
        td_size = $alltds.length();
    jsonText += "{";
    $.each($alltds, function(i){
      jsonText += "\"" + $allHeads.eq(i).text() + "\":\"";
      if (i == 0){ // you have a strange condition, will leave it up to u
           // append link
           jsonText += $(this).find("a").attr("href"); // i remove "" for better readability 
      }else{
          // append text
           jsonText += $(this).text();
      }

   });
jsonText += "}";


    $('#content').text(jsonText); // cheaper than html
});
```

**I have not tested this yet.**

You can also create a json object directly (wouldn't affect how fast though), like this

```
var mynewjson = {};
```

Then inside a loop:

```
mynewjson[name] = value;
```